# Backing up folder using Powershell Copy-Item cmdlet

Tags: file, powershell, backup, copy-item

I want to backup all files on a volume that have changed in the past 24 hours. I want the backup folder to keep the folder structure of the original. I find that when I test my current script, the folders are all placed in root.

```
$today = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d"

$storage="D:\"
$backups="E:\"
$thisbackup = $backups+$today

New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $thisbackup
foreach ($f in Get-ChildItem $storage -recurse)
{
    if ($f.LastWriteTime -lt ($(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)))
    {
        Copy-Item $f.FullName -Destination $thisbackup -Recurse
    }
}
Write-Host "The backup is complete"
```

It also seems to be copying ALL files in these folders.

Can I get some assistance on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($f.LastWriteTime -lt ($(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)))
```

should be

```
if ($f.LastWriteTime -gt ($(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)))
```

Your folders are all placed in the root because you are getting all items recursively via `Get-Childitem`.

The following should work:

```
#copy folder structure
robocopy $storage $thisbackup /e /xf *.*

foreach ($f in Get-ChildItem $storage -recurse -file)
{
    if ($f.LastWriteTime -gt ($(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)))
    {
    Copy-Item $f.FullName -Destination $thisbackup$($f.Fullname.Substring($storage.length))
    }
}
```

Comment: I had thought of separately creating the folder structure but I did not know how.Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's telling me there's a problem with the second path in:

Copy-Item $storage -destination $thisbackup -recurse -container

It says that $thisbackup cannot be a unc path or drive but it's actually a folder in the backup drive.

Comment: Hi Paul, will try next time I can. I had difficulty with robocopy before because it wasn't preserving the folder structure. This should work quite well. thanks for the assistance.